# How to handle switch case on a large ListView with multiple items

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have a ListView which has around 50 items. Depending on what list item is  clicked, I need to display different output. User can also check multiple list items.

I am using Switch case for handling this but the code becomes lengthy when the list is too big. For example, my list has around 50 items. Can someone advise how to handle when a user clicks on a ListView in this scenario. Thanks!

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            CheckedTextView selectedItem = (CheckedTextView) view;
            boolean isChecked = selectedItem.isChecked();
            Log.e("TAG","item clicked position = " + position + " isChecked = " + isChecked);
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                 //code comes here
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //code comes here
                    break;
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    case 40:
                      //code
                       break;

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: It all depends on what your logic does. If it can be grouped, do so.

Comment: I cannot group them. For each item clicked it will display a form with the output values.

Answer (score 0):

Is it html form ? You can do another thing is, Just Pass position/data to the next activity and based on that position or data you can achieve your desire goal.

Hope you get the point.